# Where does the name come from on Mail.app?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, gmail

I tried to use OS X's `Mail.app`, but when I connected it using gmail, the authentication window showed my real name in Chinese character in the first text field. The other two fields are mail and password, so I didn't log in to my gmail account yet. However, it looks like the `Mail.app` already knows my real name, and I wonder where it gets the information from.

My Apple account and iCloud account use my real name in English. So I want to check out where my Chinese character name was found and then fix it and change it to English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pulled from your 'me' contact in Contacts.app.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't remember there is `me` contact in the `Contacts.app` and my email there was the one that was deleted 3 years ago...